# Argument polymorphism in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, polymorphism

Suppose I have a hierarchy of classes:

```kotlin
interface I

class A: I
class B: I
class C: I
```

If I want to implement code that is polymorphic wrt. the `I` hierarchy, but outside of it, right now this is the only solution I can see:

```kotlin
fun f(x: I) = when (x) {
    is A -> f(x)
    is B -> f(x)
    is C -> f(x)
    else -> error("Unsupported ${x.javaClass}")
}

private fun f(a: A) = TODO()
private fun f(b: B) = TODO()
private fun f(c: C) = TODO()
```

Is there any way to achieve automatic (not manual) polymorphism on the dynamic type of an ***argument*** in Kotlin?

For example, a dynamic language like Groovy would invoke the right `f()` according to the runtime type of argument x, without the need of a generic `f()` that performs an explicit `when`.

Comment: I don't think you can without reflection. For this to work in a strongly typed language like Kotlin, the compiler would have to exhaustively search for all possible subtypes of I and make sure each one has a corresponding overload. But that could not guarantee future-proofing, or safe library use. If another module using this module declared another subtype of I, it could not handled by this function.

Comment: @Tenfour04 It's already not handled by the function, because the else throws an error. But apparently this is called "multiple dispatch" and is a known no-no in most languages :-(

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately there would be no way to do this, outside of what you have already mentioned by checking the types one by one.

It's quite apparent why it would be a bad design decision if it was allowed with a simple example. Suppose we have the same setup to yours above but without a function that accepts a `C` as input.

```
interface I

class A: I
class B: I
class C: I

private fun f(a: A) = TODO()
private fun f(b: B) = TODO()
```

Then what would you expect to happen with this call?

```
f(C())
```

There would have to be an exception thrown or some sort of compile time checking to prevent this being allowed, but it would definitely be a bit of a departure from the safe coding style that Kotlin is supposed to enforce.